# Java. Использование меньше одного байта для хранения объекта

Tags: java, char

Допустим нужно загрузить словарик состоящий только из русских слов, и работать с ним дальше. Знаю что мне не нужно будет использовать регистр, и какие либо символы. Взяв самое простое/мелкое, что мне известно - char я имею 1 байт, т.е. 8 бит и 256 разных значений. Если алфавит уместится и в 6 бит (64), то почему бы не выкинуть "лишнее".

Если это и можно сделать, нужно потратить время на "упаковку" и в дальнейшем на "распаковку". От того и 2 вопроса:

1. Можно ли?
2. Есть ли смысл?

Comment: насколько мне известно, в java есть такая штука, как выравнивание. Взять тот же boolean, значение его можно уместить в один бит, но на самом деле это далеко не так - https://habrahabr.ru/post/136883/ Так что я бы не рекомендовал пытаться экономить на байтах, т.к. результат может быть совсем не тот который ожидался.

Comment: char не один байт. char достаточно для хранения любого unicode символа, коих больше чем 256 (на несколько порядков).

Comment: Про юникод первый раз слышу...